# Entering safe posts to a web site

Tags: javascript, text, editor

My task is to create a web page, where users can enter posts (something like discussion forum). I would like to enable basic text formatting (bold, italic etc.) and usege of external links. There are a lot of JS text editor components doing the job, but I am afraid, the users will input malicious text (e.g. embedded JS code) as well. Is there a component / way, how to enable such posts hand in hand with managing my site security?

Answer (score 0):

Finally it looks like using of BBCode compliant editor is the best way - all HTML tags will be striped off and only BBCode tags will remain. CKEditor with BBCode plugin (http://ckeditor.com/addon/bbcode) seems to be my favourite choice for the task.